# Unix standard directory to put custom executables or scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, directory-structure

If I have a custom shell script or program that I created myself or downloaded from the web and I want to be able to execute this from the CLI, is there the standard location to put this in Linux/Unix directory structure?

```
/usr/bin ?
/usr/local/bin ?
/usr/lib ?
/usr/sbin ?
/bin ?
/sbin ?
/var ?
```

I usually put it under my `~/bin` directory and add it to the PATH, but it doesn't seem clean. And every time I download a new program, I have to add it to the PATH again.

Comment: I suggest `man hier`.

Comment: If your ~/bin is on the PATH, then all programs you put in ~/bin should also be on your path... What do you mean you have to put it on the PATH again?

Comment: I put the programs inside another subfolder: ~/bin/xyz, ~/bin/abc. So I have to put each one of those in PATH.

Comment: You would have to do the same no matter where you put it then. If you put /usr/bin/xyz, then you'd have to add that to the path also.

Comment: Well, ok, ignoring the PATH issue. Would it be better to put it in ~/bin or /usr/bin? Just want to know if there's the standard/cleaner way of organizing downloaded apps.

Comment: For the record: an answer to a similar question can be found at http://serverfault.com/questions/139451/where-is-a-good-permanent-place-to-install-custom-bash-scripts

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` exists precisely for this purpose: for system-wide installation. For your own private use, `~/bin` is the de facto standard.

If you want to keep each binary in its own subdirectory, you can do that, and add a symlink to a directory already in your `PATH`.  So, for example:

```
curl -o $HOME/downloads/fnord http://fnord.example.com/script.exe
ln -s $HOME/downloads/fnord $HOME/bin/
```

This assumes `$HOME/bin` is in your `PATH`.

There are tools like [`stow`](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) which do this -- and much more -- behind the scenes for you.

Comment: As a tip for Mac users: If you choose ´~/bin´ and don't want this directory to show up i Finder, you can make it invisible with [SETFILE(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/SetFile.1.html): ´setfile -a V ~/bin´ for making invisible and ´setfile -a v ~/bin´ for making visible again. Note that this requires the [Xcode Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: @tripleee: Is there a de facto standard directory for scripts (bash, perl, etc.) ? I'm thinking of e.g. ~/etc? The point is that you do not backup/track with a cvs/.. in the same way scripts and binaries.

Comment: @phs `bin` is for all kinds of executables, scripts or proper binaries. If you want them under direct version control, putting all of your `bin` in version control is certainly an option; though more commonly, you have a separate project for each, or at least each distinct group. When you release a new version, install it into your own `bin`. Or if you're serious about dog-fooding and/or have too few surprises in your life, put a symlink to your development version in your `bin`.

Comment: Thanks, I did a ln -s /usr/local/bin /root/ to better keep track of executables and respect both standards ;)

Comment: @capitano666 Not sure what you means with "both standards". The home directory of `root` should normally contain very little, as it's for stuff which is useful to `root` only.

Comment: @tripleee in my case root is the only one allowed to modify the /usr/local/bin contents. Nevermind though, I was just pointing out that my symlink happened to conform to what you called the "de facto standard"

Comment: I don't see the benefit. `/usr/local/bin` should go early in your `PATH`; duplicating the same entries as symlinks in another directory in your `PATH` will only make path searches slower.

Comment: I use `~/bin` and add the line `export $PATH=$PATH:~/bin` to `~/.bash_profile` so that I can have this be a part of `$PATH` when I log on. I only keep the executable binaries here, though - no downloads.

Comment: As an aside, there would normally not be any reason to `export` this variable again; it will already have been exported by the shell.

Comment: @erm3nda `sbin` isn't actually for `sudo` specifically. This directory generally contains executables which are not useful to non-admin users.

Comment: @tripleee is that true for all distros? thx

Comment: More than that, this is by no means just Linux, though I believe it's also codified in the LSB.

Answer (score 18):

This may vary slightly depending on the Unix flavour. I'm assuming Linux here (although this could apply to OSX). According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) (link obtained from the [Linux Standard Base working group](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb)):

> The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
>   installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
>   overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for
>   programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not
>   found in `/usr`.
>
> Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local` rather
>   than `/usr` unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software
>   in `/usr`.

`/usr/local/bin` is often on the path by default.

Note that you should only put the executable or a link to it in `/usr/local/bin`, the rest may have to go in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/share`.

The `/opt` tree might also be sensible:

> `/opt` is reserved for the installation of add-on application software
>   packages.
>
> A package to be installed in /opt must locate its static files in a
>   separate `/opt/<package>` or `/opt/<provider>` directory tree, where
>   `<package>` is a name that describes the software package and `<provider>`
>   is the provider's LANANA registered name.
>
> [...]
>
> The directories /opt/bin, /opt/doc, /opt/include, /opt/info, /opt/lib,
>   and /opt/man are reserved for local system administrator use. Packages
>   may provide "front-end" files intended to be placed in (by linking or
>   copying) these reserved directories by the local system administrator,
>   but must function normally in the absence of these reserved
>   directories.

(You could make your own link from `/opt/your-package/bin/executable` into `/opt/bin`, and put `/opt/bin` on the `PATH` if it's not already there.)