# unix commands about executable file

Tags: unix, executable

In a unix pc computer there is a directory which has the excetuable program example.
If someone while is inside the directory and he tried the above commands:

```
> example
example: command not found
>./example
Hello world!
>
```

1)why the program did not run at the first time?
2)why the program run the second time?
3)what it needs for the first try for the program to run successfully?

and another one question different from the above is
with which command in the unix operation system we can check the size of a file named example11?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168432/unix-standard-directory-to-put-custom-executables-or-scripts

Comment: You already got good answers for all your questions. One more method to check the size of a file (easy to read and understand) is `du -h <filename>`. In your case `du -h example11`.

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation of [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), [intro(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/intro.1.html), [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html), [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html), [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html), [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Most [shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) (notably `bash`) are using the `PATH` environment variable to find executables. The `command not found` message is probably after failure of `execvp` in your shell (or more probably because the shell did not found any file executable to pass to `execve` after [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)).

Consider editing your `~/.bashrc` file if you want to change it (i.e. set your `PATH`).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). BTW, [GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you could study its [source](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) code.

Type `/bin/ls --help` or simply `ls --help`. Then try `ls -l example1` to list the file named `example1`

Read also about [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), e.g. [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Then try `ls -l exampl*` but understand first that the shell is expanding `exampl*` before passing arguments to `/bin/ls`

Comment: I need short answers and basically the two questions i dont know is the third one and the fourth with size.

Comment: You need to understand things. And that require time and reading. Short answers might not be enough, and nobody will give you here a detailed answer that is documented in many other references, including the ones I gave you above.

Comment: I love detail answers :) +1

Answer (score 1):

1) Your shell did not know where `example` is located.

2) Here, you specify that `example` is located in the current directory. Now, your shell can find it and run it.

3) For the first attempt to run successfully, `example` needs to be in a directory that is a place known to your shell as one that has a lot of programs in it. To see which directories fit this criterion, run `echo $PATH`. To add the directory with `example` in it to your `$PATH`, run `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/directory`.

Lastly, run `ls -l example11` to find information about that file.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you run an executable shell will look if that executable is present in  environment variable `$PATH`, since the path was not present in `$PATH` variable it failed to run the executable.
2. You are telling shell where to find your executable. So `.` means current directory and `/` is path separator. So that means, look in the current folder for the executable name `example`.
3. In order to run your executable like (case 1) you need to do the following:
   On bash:

   `PATH=$PATH:/home/cprogtes/ ; export PATH`

   (Assuming `example` is present in `/home/cprogtes` directory.)

   Or, You can add the following entry in your `.bash_profile` which is present in home directory.

   `export PATH=$PATH:/home/cprogtes/`
4. To check the file size you can use the command `du -h <filename>`.