# Is it necessary to install hadoop in /usr/local?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to build a hadoop cluster with four nodes.

The four machines are from my school's lab and I found their */usr/local* are mount from a same public disk which means their */usr/local* are identical.

The problem is, I can not start data node on slaves because the hadoop files are always the same(like *tmp/dfs/data*).

I am planning to configure and insatll hadoop in other dirs like /opt .

The problem is I found almost all the installation tutorial ask us to install it in */usr/local* , so I was wondering will there be any bad consequence if I install hadoop in other place like */opt* ?

Btw, I am using **Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: Maybe see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168432/unix-standard-directory-to-put-custom-executables-or-scripts

Comment: For the record: this site is actually about **programming** problems. Its nice that you got an answer quickly; but to a certain degree, your question is offtopic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `HADOOP_HOME` points to where you extracted the hadoop binaries, then it shouldn't matter.

You'll also want to update `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`, for example.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop_x.yy
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

For reference, I have some configuration files inside of `/etc/hadoop`.

(Note: [Apache Ambari](http://ambari.apache.org/) makes installation easier)

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all necessary to install hadoop under `/usr/local`. That location is generally used when you install single node hadoop cluster (although it is not mandatory). As long as you have following variables specified in `.bashrc`, any location should work.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=<path-to-hadoop-install-dir>
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```